# Cannot get imports to work in web.py project

Tags: python, module, web.py, importerror

I'm trying to create a basic blogging application in Python using Web.Py. I have started without a direcotry structure, but soon I needed one. So I created this structure:

```
Blog/
├── Application/
│   ├── App.py
│   └── __init__.py
|
├── Engine/
│   ├── Connection/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── MySQLConnection.py
│   ├── Errors.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
├── Models/
│   ├── BlogPostModel.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── start.py
└── Views/
    ├── Home.py
    └── __init__.py
```

`start.py` imports `Application.App`, which contains Web.Py stuff and imports `Blog.Models.BlogPostModel`, which imports `Blog.Engine.Connection.MySQLConnection`.
`Application.App` also imports `Engine.Errors` and `Views.Home`. All these imports happen inside contructors, and all code inside all files are in classes. When I run `python start.py`, which contains these three lines of code:

```
from Application import App
app = App.AppInstance()
app.run()
```

The following stack trace is printed:

```
Blog $ python start.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 2, in <module>
    Blog = App.AppInstance()
  File "/home/goktug/code/Blog/Application/App.py", line 4, in __init__
    from Blog.Views import Home
ImportError: No module named Blog.Views
```

But according to what I understand from some research, this should run, at least until it reaches something after App.py. *Can anyone tell where I made the mistake?* (I can provide more code on request, but for now I'm stopping here, as this one is getting messier and messier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App.py` contains the statement

```
from Blog.Views import Home
```

So `Blog` needs to be among the list of directories Python searches for modules (`sys.path`). That can be arranged in various ways.

1. Since you are starting the app with `python start.py`, the directory
   containing `start.py` is automatically added to the search path. So
   you could change

   ```
   from Blog.Views import Home
   ```

   to

   ```
   from Views import Home
   ```
2. Another option would be to move `start.py` up one level, out of the
   `Blog` directory. Then when you call `python start.py`, the
   directory containing `start.py` will also be the directory
   containing `Blog`. So Python would find `Blog` when executing `from
   Blog.Views ...`
3. Finally, you could add the `Blog` directory to your PYTHONPATH environment
   variable.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but when I run the app a key error is thrown: <type 'exceptions.KeyError'> at /
u'Home'

Comment: That sounds like an error in code not shown (and unrelated to this question). Please open a new question and post more details (full stack trace and error message plus relevant code).

Comment: Thanks, I'm writing the quesiton now.

Answer (score 1):

You can only import the module `Blog` if its parent directory (not `Blog` itself) is on python's path.

If you run your program from the `Blog` directory like you do, you can only imort `Views` directly, like you do with `Application.App`:

```
from Views import Home
```

instead of

```
from Blog.Views import Home
```

in your `Application/App.py`.