# Web.py NameError When Importing Module in Module

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, web.py

I am creating a web app using web.py on python 2.7.3.
I have the following folder structure:

```
start_app.py
/app
   __init__.py
   /models
      __init__.py
      ActionModel.py
      AreaModel.py
   /controllers
      __init__.py
      world.py
   /views
```

Whenever I freshly start the app using `python start_app.py`, and visit `world/surrounding` I get the following error

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'> at /world/surrounding
cannot import name AreaModel
Python  /home/dev/app/models/ActionModel.py in <module>, line 13
Web     GET http://localhost:5000/world/surrounding
```

Line 13 is simply: `from app.models import AreaModel` but I don't see why python is complaining here.

If I comment this importing line, it runs fine. However, if I call a different URL, e.g. `world/view`, I get an error that AreaModel is not defined. Once I uncomment the line, it works fine again for all cases (i.e. /surrounding and /view).

I am suspecting that this has something to do with the fact that I am "importing in circles", i.e. world.py imports AreaModel, AreaModel imports ActionModel and ActionModel imports AreaModel.
I doubt that this is 'the pythonic way' to do things or even the 'MVC way', so I would very much appreciate your enlightening me how to do this properly.

Note: app is not in my PYTHONPATH, but I don't think it is needed here, since start_app.py is in the top-level directory and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221021/cannot-get-imports-to-work-in-web-py-project) all modules should be available.

Basically, what it comes down to is:
I need the models' functionalities in both the controllers and the models. Is it good practice to "import in circles"? Or is there a nicer approach to do this?
Also, is this problem related to python in general or just web.py?

**Update:**
Added **init**.py files, I had them, but did not include in original question. Sorry for that.

**Update:**
ActionModel.py includes (among others) a class named BaseAction and a few functions, which return instances or subclasses of BaseAction depending on what type of Action we are dealing with. They are called using e.g. `ActionModel.get_by_id()`

@matthew-trevor : Are you suggesting in *a)* that I should move those functions `get_by_id()` into a class ActionModel?

```
#actionmodel.py
class ActionModel(object):
    def __init__(arg1, arg2, area_class):
        self.area = area_class()

    def get_by_id(self, id):
        return BaseAction(id)

class BaseAction(object):
    def __init__(id):
        pass
```

I don't see how this should remedy my import problems though.

Answer (score 0):

**The Immediate Problem**

You cannot import from folders, but you *can* import from packages. You can turn any folder into a package by adding an `__init__.py` file to it:

```
start_app.py
/app
   __init__.py
   /models
      __init__.py
      ActionModel.py
      AreaModel.py
   /controllers
      __init__.py
      world.py
   /views
      __init__.py
```

I'm guessing that `ActionModel.py` includes a class of the same name. If so, I recommend renaming the file to `actionmodel.py` to distinguish it from the class.

**Circular imports**

> Is it good practice to "import in circles"? Or is there a nicer
>   approach to do this?

It's not only bad practice, it just won't work. There are a couple of ways to get around this, which will mostly depend on what you're trying to do:

a. In `AreaModel`, import the `ActionModel` module and then reference anything you want to use in it via attribute lookup and vice versa:

```py
# areamodel.py
import actionmodel

def foo():
    action = actionmodel.ActionModel(...)
```

As long as the references are inside class or function definitions, it will only occur at run time and not during importing, so the circular reference is avoided.

b. Turn `models` into a module and put both `ActionModel` and `AreaModel` code inside it.

c. Move the shared code/functionality for `ActionModel` and `AreaModel` into a base module they both import from.

d. Make your `ActionModel` class (or whatever) accept a class as an input, then pass `AreaModel` into it in `world.py` (ditto for `AreaModel`). This way, `ActionModel` doesn't need to contain a reference to `AreaModel`, it just has to know what to do with it:

```py
# actionmodel.py
class ActionModel(object):
    def __init__(arg1, arg2, area_class):
        self.area = area_class()

# areamodel.py
class AreaModel(object):
    def __init__(action_class):
        self.action = action_class()

# world.py
from actionmodel import ActionModel
from areamodel import AreaModel

action = ActionModel('foo', 'bar', AreaModel)
area = AreaModel(ActionModel)
```

This is known as object composition.

Comment: I had __init__.py files so this is not the problem. Thank you anyway for pointing it out. I added them.